# Add JsTag only on home site

Tags: typo3, typoscript

GDay,

I need to add a script on the home page only. The only method I found was with the pages PID, which I dont know..

Whats the best practice to include a script only on the start page?
If I need the PID, how do I find it?

Kind regards, a typo3 noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the backend hover the start page on the PageTree with mouse pointer so it will show you the UID of page (ie. `id=1`)

Then use a **[condition](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html)** in your TypoScript template

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 1]
  // include script on page with UID 1 only
[end]
```

Comment: The answer of biesior is absolutely right. But there is also a new condition which is shorter and *sweeter* -> check http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#id44 -> page|uid = 1